# Prove that $A \subset B$ if and only if $A \setminus B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

Prove that $A \subset B$ if and only if $A \setminus B = \emptyset$.

What is the correct and mathematically strict way to prove the above? (slightly different than [Prove that if $A \setminus B = \emptyset$, then $A \subseteq B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573484/prove-that-if-a-setminus-b-emptyset-then-a-subseteq-b) )

Comment: The symbol $\subset$ means inclusion or proper inclusion?

Comment: The symbol $\subset$ must mean regular inclusion, same as in your linked answer, because otherwise it would be false. So the only difference between your question and your linked question is that yours is an equivalence, so you need to prove the converse as well.

Comment: It's not true if the inclusion is strict. Consider $A = B$.

Comment: Nice question. In their book http://books.google.pt/books?output=html_text&id=7U8-rs-S2boC&q=300 they mention "$A \subset A$ holds true for any $A$". So I suppose they use the sign $\subset$ instead of $\subseteq$, right?

Comment: [My answer to the question you link to](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/642479/11994) answers this exact question, in exactly the same way as [GDumphart](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/124970/gdumphart)'s [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1042510/11994) does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
A \subset B \ \ :\Leftrightarrow \ \  & \forall x \ : \ (x \in A) \rightarrow (x \in B) \\
\Leftrightarrow \ \  & \forall x \ : \ \lnot (x \in A) \lor (x \in B)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
A \backslash B = \emptyset \ \ :\Leftrightarrow \ \  & \forall x \ : \ x \notin A \backslash B \\
\Leftrightarrow \ \  & \forall x \ : \ \lnot (x \in A \backslash B) \\
\Leftrightarrow \ \  & \forall x \ : \ \lnot ((x \in A) \land \lnot (x \in B)) \\
\Leftrightarrow \ \  & \forall x \ : \ \lnot (x \in A) \lor \lnot(\lnot (x \in B)) \\
\Leftrightarrow \ \  & \forall x \ : \ \lnot (x \in A) \lor (x \in B) \\
\Leftrightarrow \ \  & A \subset B \ \ \ 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

If $A\subset B$, $\forall x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$, so $A\setminus B=\emptyset$. I think this trivial.

Now, suppose $A\setminus B=\emptyset$. If $\exists x\in A$ but $x\notin B$, $x\in A\setminus B$ by the definition of set minus, which is a contradiction. So $x\in B$ and $A\subset B$.